# A more beautiful TypeScript anonymous class declaration?

Tags: typescript

Is there a more beautiful way to express an anonymous class(?) with typed members in typeScript than this?

```
class Foo {
    member = {
        aNumber = <number>undefined;
        aBoolean = <bool>undefined;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The only *anonymous* alternative would be:

```
class Foo {
    member: { aNumber?: number; aBoolean?: bool; } = {
        aNumber: undefined,
        aBoolean: undefined
    }
}
```

You're usually better off just writing an `interface` so you can name the type.

Answer (score 10):

Since members are undefined by default you could simply go with:

```
class Foo {
    member:{aNumber:number;aBoolean:bool;} = <any>{};
}
```

Comment: but then "member" is undefined - not member.aNumber / member.aBoolean

Comment: Updated to make `member` not be undefined to begin with using a type assertion : http://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/type-assertion.html

Answer (score 4):

In newer versions of typescript, this can be achieved using optional properties:

```
class Foo {
    member: { aNumber?: number; aBoolean?: boolean; } = {}
}
```